# NGINX try_files + alias directives

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve request to /blog subdirectory of a site with the php code, located in a folder outside document root directory. Here's my host config:

```
server {
    server_name  local.test.ru;
    root   /home/alex/www/test2;

    location /blog {
        alias   /home/alex/www/test1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

And I get for requests like

wget -O - http://local.test.ru/blog/nonExisting

just a code of index.php file from /home/alex/www/test2/ folder.

However, this config:

```
server {
    server_name  local.test.ru;
    root   /home/alex/www/test2;

    location /blog {
        alias   /home/alex/www/test1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog$is_args$args;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

gives me index.html file from /home/alex/www/test2/.
Please give me a clue - why? And how can I force NGINX to process /home/alex/www/test1/index.php instead?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is [a long standing bug in nginx](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). But you can work around by using the `root` directive again. Kind of a hack, but at least it works.

```
server {
    index       index.php;
    root        /home/alex/www/test2;
    server_name local.test.ru;

    location /blog {
        root      /home/alex/www/test1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot believe this bug is still opened after 2 years !

Comment: Are you sure this workaround works? I can't get it to work no matter what. Could you verify? `root` and `alias` are not interchangeable.

Comment: The definitely aren't interchangeable. Post your specific problem and I'll see if I can help you (send me the URL to your new question).

Comment: Simply replacing `alias` with `root` won't work. In the OP's case, `http://localhost/blog` will search in `/home/alex/www/test1`, whereas it here will look in `/home/alex/www/test1/blog`. Although `/blog/nonExisting` is likely to fail in both cases, `/blog` will not work where it did previously.

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 3 years !

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 4 years !

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 5 years !

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 6 years !

Comment: Did I miss something, but the ticket was created in 2012. So How did you count 6 years? :)

Comment: I still have this issue, Oct 2017

Comment: March 2018. 6 years

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 6 years and 6 months !

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 8 years !

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still... wait, is this still a thing?

Comment: Keep traditions alive! Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 9 years!

Comment: here we go, 10 years yeah!

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 10 years and 10 days ! (someone added 1 year :D)

Comment: yep 11 years since that bug was opened. that must be on purpose

Comment: Also cannot believe this bug is still opened after 11 years !

Answer (score 41):

We could not get it to work by specifying root within the location block. The solution for us was to use alias instead. Note that it is necessary repeat the location's path twice in the try_files directive, and then also in the .php configuration block:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /app/frontend/www;

    location /backend/ {

        alias /app/backend/www/;

        # serve static files direct + allow friendly urls
        # Note: The seemingly weird syntax is due to a long-standing bug in nginx: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97
        try_files $uri $uri/ /backend//backend/index.php?$args;

        location ~ /backend/.+\.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $proxied_https;
            fastcgi_pass phpfiles;
        }

    } # / location

}
```

Source: [nginx/conf.d/app.conf](https://github.com/neam/docker-stack/blob/31c12e73fa65eebdcd025f58767b46d4d26e0aa8/stacks/neam/debian-php-nginx/stack/nginx/conf.d/app.conf#L42-L44) from the [debian-php-nginx stack](https://github.com/neam/docker-stack/tree/develop/stacks/neam/debian-php-nginx/stack) in [the docker-stack project](https://github.com/neam/docker-stack/)

Comment: This worked for me putting a laravel install on /api location

Comment: "Note that it is necessary repeat the location's path twice in the try_files directive"  .....?!  It looks so wrong but actually works! Thanks, would have never figured that out!

Comment: I COULD KISS YOU NOW

Comment: Thanks man, I was gonna kill someone until i see your post. This bug has taken me almost the whole afternoon to find a solution.

Comment: What's that double slash for ? `/backend//backend/`

Comment: @DylanHunt There is a bug in nginx that makes it required to repeat the location directive twice here. Why? No idea

Comment: It also works foe me. About the double slash it seems to be related to having a trailing slash at the `location` block.

Answer (score 20):

There is another workaround which gives more flexibility. It consists of a `proxy_pass` directive which points on 127.0.0.1 and another `server` block.

In your case it should looks like this:

```
upstream blog.fake {
    server 127.0.0.1;
}
server {
    server_name local.test.ru;
    root /home/alex/www/test2;
    index index.html;

    location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://blog.fake/;
    }
}
server {
    server_name blog.fake;
    root /home/alex/www/test1;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Comment: elegant solution

Comment: This is by far the best option!

Comment: I really like this solution, makes it really easy understand what is happening and doesnt require complex nesting.

Comment: This deserves so much more recognition

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with: NGINX 1.14.0, PHP 7.4, Laravel  8.2.  (The other solutions listed here didn't work.)

Comment: I've implemented this fix but I experience an issue with the first URL, can see an example here in the 'Attempted fix': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093486/nginx-alias-breaks-due-to-try-files-uri-alias-bug

Comment: This solution is great, but it also needs to re-add the `/blog` part to the `REQUEST_URI` with `fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI /blog$request_uri;` to be completely transparent to PHP.