# Nginx root inside location not working

Tags: php, nginx

I am using nginx 1.8 and knowing about the [alias/try_files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426812/nginx-try-files-alias-directives) bug i wrote the following nginx conf:

```
root /var/www/
location  /foo/ {
   root /var/www/projects/bar/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;

}
```

in which i get a 404, but if i write the following way (which should point to the same location)

```
  root /var/www/
  location   ~ ^/foo/(.*)$  {
    try_files /projects/bar/public/$uri /projects/bar/public/$uri/ /projects/bar/public/index.php;

 }
```

i get the contents.
Why  the other root seems not to be applyied?

Comment: Have a look at the nginx error log, it'll show you the final path it's trying to use. I think it may be trying /var/www/projects/bar/public/foo/

Comment: Yes that would be true for $uri and $uri/ but not for index.php (that was the final destination). No noticeable error on error.log, funy thing though i created a new virtual server with the same root and all work as intended.  I just wanted to know why 1 is wrong in what concerns the index.php