# Nginx - rewrite rules for folders

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, url-rewriting

I've got VPS running with `Ubuntu` + `Nginx`.

It is accessible via browser through: `example.com`

Now, I want to create 2 folders in `/var/www/html/`: `laravel` and `magento` so that both locations host separate applications, accordingly magento and laravel:

- **example.com/laravel/** to access the Laravel app
- **example.com/magento/** to access Magento store

Please advice how shall I set Nginx rewrite rules in `/etx/nginx/sites-available/default` to achieve this?

Or maybe there is other way to achieve this?

** EDIT **

```
etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

     location /laravel/ {
       root /var/www/html;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

     location /2.2.1/ {
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/2.2.1;
        include /var/www/html/2.2.1/nginx.conf.sample;
     }
 }
```

---

```
/var/www/html/2.2.1/nginx.conf.sample


set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/2.2.1; 
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=7G \n max_execution_time=1800";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=7G \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: The behavior you're describing would be the default after adding those subdirectories. Assuming the root directory is already set to `/var/www/html`, creating folder `foo` in the webroot would allow you to browse to `example.com/foo/` without any further configuration needed. You might need rewrite rules if you wanted it served as `foo.example.com` or something else.

Comment: That's how it is set up already. Folders `laravel` and `magento` are already in `/var/www/html`. I just need now to set nginx rewrite rules for each of those folders separately

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, your desired behavior has already been achieved. If you need to add further rewrites targeting the `laravel/` or `magento/` directories specifically, you would use a `location` block for them and add the rewrite rules there. See https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ for some examples. Is there any specific behavior you're trying to add here?

Comment: Please see my updated post. There is `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` source code attached. As you can see there are 2 location sections. The laravel section includes nginx rules for laravel. The Magento one, includes rules for magento (attached too). It's not working though. Thanks!

Comment: From what you have posted currently, I am still unable to determine the root of the issue. Assuming your main document root is `/var/www/html`, the `root` directive inside the `location /laravel/` block is redundant. Also assuming the Laravel directory is `/var/www/html/laravel/`, that location block should be correct. A request to `http://example.com/laravel/index.php` should succeed. There's a lot going on in the Magento config, but I see no obvious errors there either. Perhaps specific examples of the incorrect behavior you're observing would help, or any errors you might find in the logs.

Comment: Also, nginx seems to love using `server` blocks as the solution to everything, but that may be a good way to nail down the problem here. Maybe configure `server` blocks for `laravel.local` and `magento.local` which hold their relevant configs, then in the main `server` block, define locations for Laravel and Magento, as you've done, only use `proxy_pass` to point to the other server blocks. Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45642689/4087397). This would simplify what each server block is doing, and may help iron out the issue.